# Easily customizable graph editor

Tags: java, graph, editor

I'd like to customize an existing graph editor (I'm talking about [graphs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_%28mathematics%29) with nodes and vertices) in Java. I'd like to be able to add different kinds of nodes, connections etc. The resulting diagram will then be used for code generations. Do you have any recommendations as to which existing (open source) graph editor/visualization toolkit in Java to use?

Comment: Are you looking for an API to build your own graph editor/code generator, or a tool that you can use right now to edit graphs that generate code?

Comment: It could be both. I'm not interested in code generation based on UML, but I'd like to generate a method that instantiates an in-memory graph structure (with Node and Connection objects)

Comment: Something like neo4j but then in memory?

Comment: Yes something like that, but it wouldn't represent(store) data, but decision points.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[JGraph](http://www.jgraph.com/jgraph.html) is a nice tool. An other great option is [JGraphT](http://www.jgrapht.org/visualizations.html). But if you want better interactivity and Dijkstra short paths etc. then you need [JUNG2](http://jung.sourceforge.net/). JUNG2 allows you to have any kind of vertices and edges. Your graph is created with generics, like this: `Graph<V, E>`. You can use any class you may need for V (vertex) and E (edge). Scaling and transforming is also easy to implement and very flexible.